# How to express "a little bit of" a mass noun outside of the nominative or accusative case

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

How do you say "a little (small amount) of" a mass noun when the noun phrase is not in the nominative or accusative case or is the object of a preposition?

Normally a partitive genitive is used, e.g. *paulum aquae* = a little water, but this construction is allowed with neuter pronouns and adjectives "*only* if they are nominative or accusative without a preposition" (Bradley's Arnold Rev. Mountford §295.c). So how would you translate something like the following:

> He treated the wound with a little medicine.
>
> *Vulnus ___ cūrāvit.*

...if **paulō medicāmentī* and **per paulum medicāmentī* are not acceptable? The same type of problem could apply to other situations besides the instrumental ablative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use *paulus* adjectively, that is to say:

> *Vulnus paulo medicamento curavit.*

The [edition of Bradley's Arnold I found online](https://archive.org/details/practicalintrod00arnouoft/page/194/mode/2up) made this clear by giving the example "*Tanto sanguine*, not *tanto sanguinis*".